# JPA persistence.xml With SBT Project

Tags: java, scala, jpa, sbt, kundera

I placed the `persistence.xml` file in `history/src/main/resources/META-INF/` yet I am still getting an error.

**Where should I be putting the XML file, and what should I change with SBT?**

**SBT:**

```
lazy val history = (project in file("history"))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies += "com.impetus.kundera.client" % "kundera-cassandra" % "2.17"
  )
```

**Some Scala Code:  (Java Conversion is Straightforward)**

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    new HistoryCore()

  }
}

class HistoryCore {

  val emf: EntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("cassandra_pu")

  val em: EntityManager = emf.createEntityManager()
  em.persist(TradeData(DateTime.now(), 1.618))
  em.close()
  emf.close()

  // @BeanProperty dynamically adds a getter and a setter for the given variable. This keeps the code clean and the JPA implementation working
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "users", schema = "KunderaExamples@cassandra_pu")
  case class TradeData(@Id
                       @BeanProperty
                       var time: DateTime,
                       @Column(name = "price")
                       @BeanProperty
                       var price: Double)
}
```

**Error:**

```
20:45:47.537 [main] INFO  c.i.k.p.EntityManagerFactoryImpl - Loading Core
20:45:47.770 [main] INFO  c.impetus.kundera.loader.CoreLoader - Loading Kundera Core Metdata ... 
20:45:47.775 [main] INFO  c.i.k.p.EntityManagerFactoryImpl - Loading Persistence Unit MetaData For Persistence Unit(s) cassandra_pu.
20:45:47.789 [main] INFO  c.i.k.c.PersistenceUnitConfiguration - Loading Metadata from persistence.xml ...
20:45:47.794 [main] ERROR c.i.k.c.PersistenceUnitConfiguration - Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
```

**Project Structure:**

[image]

Comment: Hmm, since I still haven't figured out the issue, I'll delete my answer to hopefully get the question more interest...

Comment: I was able to hack a fix by copying the file to target->classes.  This was after digging into their source files.  The classloader method they are using seems like a very poor choice.  They should have allowed devs to submit their xml as an array since that is what they are doing anyway.  In addition this seems like a bug caused by project structure assumptions by the devs.  In the end, I opted for another library that has much better query support. (with typesafety)

Comment: I also don't like how without a single call to any of their libraries, their libraries magically load with a call to the java standard JPA lib.  I don't know if this would cause problems with other JPA implementation libs, but it sure seems like it could.  Its a shame these problems are present as it seems like the project has momentum.